# Best way to limit rate of requests sent to Facebook

Tags: node.js, mongodb, job-scheduling

I have a Messenger chatbot using Node.JS and MongoDB. Facebook limits the rate of requests per second to 40 before being converted to High-Volume, which disabled the Page Inbox tool. I don't want this to happen, so I'm finding a way to limit the rate of requests sent out.

I'd like to have a lightweight and simple solution. I thought about using `setInterval`, but I'm not sure if this is good. I also thought about using a job scheduling framework, but many of them depend on Redis. The only one I know that uses MongoDB is [agenda](https://github.com/agenda/agenda), but sadly it doesn't support rate limiter.

What should I do?

Comment: You don't need a *job scheduler*, what you need is called a *rate limiter*. If your NodeJS application is multiprocess (where you start multiple instances of the same process), you need some kind of independent storage like Redis to coordinate the rate limiter. Otherwise you can get away with a simple rate limiting Class you create yourself or otherwise.

Comment: @nicholaswmin I prefer not to use Redis. Mongo is fine